# Hypothesis of Grönwall's inequality (Evans version)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I hope this question has not alredy been asked: unfortunately there are many versions of this inequality and is difficult to find exactly the version I'm looking for.

In *Partial Differential Equations, Evans* (Appendix B2), there is the proof of the following inequality:

> **Grönwall's inequality:** Let $\eta$ be a nonnegative, absolutely continuous function on $[0,T]$, which satisfies:
> $$\eta'(t)\leq\phi(t)\eta(t)+\psi(t) \qquad a.e. \ t$$
> where $\phi,\psi$ are nonnegative summable functions on $[0,T]$, then:
> $$\eta(t)\leq e^{\int_0^t\phi(s)\ ds}\Big[\eta(0)+\int_0^t\psi(s) \ ds\Big] \qquad \forall t\in[0,T]$$
> **Proof:**
> $$\frac{d}{ds}\Big[\eta(s)e^{-\int_0^s\phi(r)\ dr}\Big]=e^{-\int_0^s\phi(r)\ dr}[\eta'(s)-\phi(s)\eta(s)]\leq e^{-\int_0^s\phi(r)\ dr}\psi(s)$$
> By integration on $[0,t]$, with $t\in[0,T]$, we have:
> $$\eta(t) e^{-\int_0^t\phi(r)\ dr}\leq \eta(0)+\int_0^t e^{-\int_0^s\phi(r)\ dr}\psi(s) \ ds\leq \eta(0)+\int_0^t\psi(s) \ ds$$
> where the last inequality follows by the nonnegativeness of $\phi,\psi$.

I can't understand how the nonnegativeness of $\eta$ is used in the proof. Is this hypothesis not necessary? I need to use it for a positive $\eta$ so this hypothesis is not a problem. It is just to be sure that I am not missing something important in the proof of the inequality.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is independent on the sign of the function $\eta$, see also the wikipedia page for [Grönwall's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality). One reason Evans only states it for nonegative functions might be that one of the applications of Grönwall's lemma is the uniqueness of solutions of linear differential equations, where you can apply Grönwall's lemma to a nonnegative function, if my memory does not fail me; in other words: he does not need the lemma in its most general form.